# Tracking a continuous instance of absence SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, gaps-and-islands

I have a table called `sickness` which is a record of when an employee is off work sick. It looks like this:

```
Date_Sick      Employee_Number
----------     ----------------
2020-06-08     001
2020-06-10     001
2020-06-11     001
2020-06-12     001
2020-06-08     002
2020-06-09     002
```

What I'm trying to do is add a new column with a unique ID to identify a unique instance of absence. A unique instance of absence is one that runs in consecutive weekdays with no breaks. Hence my output table should look like this:

```
Date_Sick      Employee_Number   Sickness_ID
----------     ----------------  -----------
2020-06-08     001               1
2020-06-10     001               2
2020-06-11     001               2
2020-06-12     001               2
2020-06-08     002               3
2020-06-09     002               3
```

I've tried creating various partitions using `LEAD/LAG` to check if the next date is only 1 day away however I'm failing to get it to work.

**AMENDMENT** this also needs to factor in only the days an individual would be working, which I can add to the table. So for any date I can add a flag to say 'Y' or 'N' to state if the employee would be expected to be in the office. So weekends would typically be a 'N'.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should ask a new question to take "working days" into account.

Comment: Good idea, I've now done this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65126701/tracking-continuous-days-of-absence-from-work-days-only-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.

Here, I think the simplest approach is `row_number()` and date arithmetics:

```
select date_sick, employee_number,
    dense_rank() over(order by employee_number,  dateadd(day, -rn, date_sick)) as sickness_id
from (
    select s.*,
        row_number() over(partition by employee_number order by date_sick) as rn
    from sickness s
) s
order by employee_number, date_sick
```

This works by comparing `date_sick` against an incrementing id, then using that information to rank the records.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f7a61cef9d09bb89653c93b7d8f84d8)** - with credits to Larnu for generating the DDL in the first place:

```
date_sick  | employee_number | sickness_id
:--------- | :-------------- | ----------:
2020-06-08 | 001             |           1
2020-06-10 | 001             |           2
2020-06-11 | 001             |           2
2020-06-12 | 001             |           2
2020-06-08 | 002             |           3
2020-06-09 | 002             |           3
```

Comment: So this works perfectly based on the example data I've provided (thank you), however when applied to my larger dataset it isn't doing it correctly. I have dates '2020-06-08' & '2020-06-10' next to each other for the same user ID and it's giving the same sickness ID

Comment: @PhilCollins: that would be surprising. Are you able to reproduce the issue in the fiddle I provided?

Comment: I figured it out, it was filtering out days after the partition was applied, so messing it up. So it works perfectly! My only challenge now is to factor in non-working days by the employee which would result in gaps in the dates however would still need to be considered as a continuation